# How do I get drivers for a WD MyBook Essential to make it run on Ubuntu(12.10)

Tags: drivers, 12.10, usb-drive

How do I get drivers for a WD MyBook Essential to make it run on Ubuntu(12.10)
the drive was running normal on WinXP before, in Ubuntu it is found but I cannot work with the data on the drive...

Comment: What data are in question? Is the drive encrypted?

Answer (score 1):

***Out of the box ..*** this device is intended for use on Windows (most variants). There are also instructions for use with Mac ('re-format drive'):

[Western Digital > MyBook Essential > User Manual](http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/UM/ENG/4779-705019.pdf)

*It has a feature (Virtual CD) that allows Windows to (auto) load drivers and utilities, to add to the "Windows experience". These are potentially a nuisance, unless you are **only** using the drive with Windows PCs.*

---

**Instructions to remove 'VCD', etc.** (from vendor's website)

[How to remove (disable / hide) the Virtual CD (VCD) for Windows or Mac OSX on a WD My Book or WD My Passport](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3835/p/228,209,316/session/L3RpbWUvMTM0MzI3MDIzOS9zaWQvR0FRbkszMmw=)

**Note:** *These instructions need to be run on Windows or Mac, and will **not** run on (Ubuntu) Linux.*

---

**Possible alternative:** (for the adventurous ..)

[Removing SmartWare from Western Digital My Book Essential USB Hard Drive](http://www.securitybeacon.com/?p=571)